# function called on page load while it must be called on onclick only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I want to call `updateRecord("+n+")` function on click Update button 
here `res.data` is the response from ajax. But when the page loads the `updareRecord` called itself. Following code is written in js file. and on click getting following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

I request to mention exact point if you don't understand any point of question instead mark it negative.

```
$.map(res.data,function(n,i){
       if (n['type'] == 1)
            html += "<tr><td>" 
                 + n['locationName'] 
                 + "</td><td>" 
                 + n['categoryName'] 
                 + "</td><td>" 
                 + n['day'] 
                 + "</td><td>" 
                 + n['status'] 
                 + "</td><td><input type='button' onclick = '"+updateRecord(n)+ "' value='Update'/></td></tr>";  
 });
```

Comment: Try removing the + symbols from around your function, basically JavaScript is running your function rather than writing it to the DOM. `+ "</td><td><input type='button' onclick = 'updateRecord(n)' value='Update'/></td></tr>";`

Comment: That's why using `onEvent` attributes is considered a bad practice.

Comment: Can you show complete code of HTML generation?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling the function already when callback function is called.
This happens right here on this line:

```
+ "</td><td><input type='button' onclick = '"+updateRecord(n)+ "' value='Update'/></td></tr>";
```

You call first updateRecord(n) and then append the return value to the text.

I would avoid adding events to DOM directly, but rather use something like this:

```
var button = $('<input type="button" value="Update" />');
button.click(function(event) {
   updateRecord(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you call the method:

```
html += "<input type='button' onclick = '"+updateRecord(n)+"' ...";
/* like this you execute the method directly, 
   like any other function call in javascript */
```

In case you'll write it like this:

```
html += "<input type='button' onclick = 'updateRecord("+n+")'...";
/* like this it is a string, and will be 
  interpreted by the javascript click eventhandler
  after adding the html string to the DOM */
```

It could work as expected, but the problem is, that you'll want to set an array/ object as parameter, which will cause an javascript error. To avoid that you could also do something like this:

```
$.map(res.data,function(n,i){
    if (n['type'] == 1) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + n['locationName'] + "</td><td>" + 
        n['categoryName'] + "</td><td>" + n['day'] + "</td><td>" + 
        n['status'] + "</td><td>" + 
        "<input class='update-button' data-value='"+ 
        /* since n is an associative array, will need 
           to stringify in a special way */
        JSON.stringify(n).replace(/'/g, "\\'")
        +"' type='button' value='Update'/></td></tr>";  
    }
});
/* bind an click event to all .update-button elements, 
whenever these elements will be appended to the DOM */
$(document).on('click','.update-button',function() {
    updateRecord($(this).data('value'));
});
```